Low GPU utilization (0-5%) with high memory usage in model training
I'm working on a machine learning project using TensorFlow (version 2.10.1) to train a convolutional neural network (CNN) on sEMG signals. While my model utilizes nearly all of the GPU memory (10.8/12 GB), I've noticed that the GPU usage remains extremely low, fluctuating between 0-5%. This is significantly impacting the training speed and overall efficiency of my model.My GPU is the RTX 3060 with 12 GB.
# Configurar GPU
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers, layers, Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix
import pickle

# 1. Preparación de los Datos
def segment_data(data, window_size, stride):
    segments = []
    num_samples = len(data)
    num_segments = (num_samples - window_size) // stride + 1
    for i in range(0, num_segments * stride, stride):
        segment = data[i:i + window_size]
        segments.append(segment)
    return np.array(segments)

def load_data(file_path_data, file_path_labels, window_size, stride):
    # Cargar datos
    datos = pd.read_csv(file_path_data, header=None)
    objetivos = pd.read_csv(file_path_labels, header=None)

    data = datos.values
    labels = objetivos.values.flatten()

    # Segmentar los datos
    segments = segment_data(data, window_size, stride)
    segments = np.transpose(segments, (0, 2, 1))
    segment_labels = labels

    num_samples = len(segment_labels)
    permutation = np.random.permutation(num_samples)
    shuffled_segments = segments[permutation]
    shuffled_labels = segment_labels[permutation]

    return shuffled_segments, shuffled_labels

def create_tf_dataset(X, y, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024)  # Mezcla los datos
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)  # Pre-fetching para optimizar el rendimiento
    return dataset

# Cargar los datos
window_size = 400
stride = 400
X, y = load_data('../CSVs/DATOS_200ms_80V_S1.csv', '../CSVs/OBJETIVOS_200MS_80V_S1.csv', window_size, stride)

# Separar en conjunto de entrenamiento y prueba
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y)

# Crear conjuntos de datos
input_shape = (12, window_size, 1)
num_classes = 18
learning_rate = 0.0001


import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

# Definir bloque secuencial con capas paralelas y conexiones residuales (ResNet style)
def sequential_block(input_tensor, filters):
    # Primera convolución estándar (principal)
    x1 = layers.Conv2D(filters, (5, 5), padding='same', dilation_rate=2, activation='gelu')(input_tensor)
    
    # Segunda convolución estándar (adicional en paralelo)
    x2 = layers.Conv2D(filters, (5, 5), padding='same', dilation_rate=2, activation='gelu')(input_tensor)
    
    # Tercera convolución estándar (adicional en paralelo)
    x3 = layers.Conv2D(filters, (5, 5), padding='same', dilation_rate=2, activation='gelu')(input_tensor)
    
    # Concatenar las salidas de las tres capas en paralelo
    x = layers.Concatenate()([x1, x2, x3])
    
    # Aplicar maxpooling y batch normalization
    #x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    
    # Conexión residual (al estilo ResNet)
    residual = layers.Conv2D(filters * 3, (1, 1), padding='same')(input_tensor)  # Para igualar dimensiones
    x = layers.Add()([x, residual])
    
    return x

# Definir el modelo de CNN
def create_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    # Primer bloque secuencial con 32 filtros
    x = sequential_block(inputs, 16)
    
    # Segundo bloque secuencial con 64 filtros
    x = sequential_block(x, 16)

    # Tercer bloque secuencial con 64 filtros
    x = sequential_block(x, 16)
    
    # Bloque final con convoluciones point-wise (1x1) y activación GELU
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (1, 1), activation='gelu')(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (1, 1), activation='gelu')(x)
    
    # Aplicar BatchNormalization
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    
    # Global MaxPooling
    x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
    
    # Capa densa con 128 unidades
    x = layers.Dense(128, activation='gelu')(x)
    
    # Capa de salida
    outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    
    # Construir el modelo
    model = models.Model(inputs, outputs)
    
    # Compilar el modelo
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model

# Parámetros del modelo
input_shape = (12, 400, 1)
num_classes = 18

# Crear el modelo
model = create_model(input_shape, num_classes)

# Mostrar el resumen del modelo
model.summary()

# 3. Función de cross-validation
from tensorflow.keras.models import clone_model  # Para clonar el modelo

def cross_validate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_folds=5, file_path='Resultados/Resultados_CNN15_S1.pkl'):
    kf = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

    validation_accs = []
    validation_f1s = []
    validation_sensitivities = []
    history_list = []

    best_val_acc = 0
    best_model_weights = None  # Aquí guardaremos los mejores pesos del modelo

    fold = 1
    for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X_train):
        print(f"--- Starting fold {fold} ---")
        # Dividir los datos para el pliegue actual
        X_train_fold, X_val_fold = X_train[train_index], X_train[val_index]
        y_train_fold, y_val_fold = y_train[train_index], y_train[val_index]

        # Crear conjuntos de datos
        train_dataset_fold = create_tf_dataset(X_train_fold, y_train_fold, batch_size=16)
        validation_dataset_fold = create_tf_dataset(X_val_fold, y_val_fold, batch_size=16)

        # Crear y compilar el modelo
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            model = create_model(input_shape=input_shape, num_classes=num_classes)

        # Entrenar el modelo
        history = model.fit(train_dataset_fold, validation_data=validation_dataset_fold, epochs=30, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=8)
        #history = model.fit(train_dataset_fold, validation_data=validation_dataset_fold, epochs=30)

        # Guardar el historial de entrenamiento para cada pliegue
        history_list.append(history.history)

        # Evaluar en el conjunto de validación
        val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(validation_dataset_fold)
        y_val_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_val_fold), axis=1)
        val_f1 = f1_score(y_val_fold, y_val_pred, average='macro')
        val_sensitivity = recall_score(y_val_fold, y_val_pred, average='macro')

        validation_accs.append(val_acc)
        validation_f1s.append(val_f1)
        validation_sensitivities.append(val_sensitivity)

        # Guardar el mejor modelo basado en la métrica de validación (ej. val_acc)
        if val_acc > best_val_acc:
            best_val_acc = val_acc
            best_model_weights = model.get_weights()  # Guardar los mejores pesos del modelo

        fold += 1

    # Calcular estadísticas de validación
    val_acc_mean, val_acc_std = np.mean(validation_accs), np.std(validation_accs)
    val_f1_mean, val_f1_std = np.mean(validation_f1s), np.std(validation_f1s)
    val_sensitivity_mean, val_sensitivity_std = np.mean(validation_sensitivities), np.std(validation_sensitivities)

    # Evaluar el conjunto de prueba usando el mejor modelo
    print("--- Evaluating on test set with the best model ---")
    final_model = create_model(input_shape=input_shape, num_classes=num_classes)
    final_model.set_weights(best_model_weights)  # Cargar los pesos del mejor modelo

    test_dataset = create_tf_dataset(X_test, y_test, batch_size=16)
    test_loss, test_acc = final_model.evaluate(test_dataset)
    y_test_pred = np.argmax(final_model.predict(X_test), axis=1)
    test_f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_test_pred, average='macro')
    test_sensitivity = recall_score(y_test, y_test_pred, average='macro')

    # Generar matriz de confusión
    conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_pred, normalize='true')

    # Guardar resultados
    resultados = {
        'validation_accuracy_mean': val_acc_mean,
        'validation_accuracy_std': val_acc_std,
        'validation_f1_mean': val_f1_mean,
        'validation_f1_std': val_f1_std,
        'validation_sensitivity_mean': val_sensitivity_mean,
        'validation_sensitivity_std': val_sensitivity_std,
        'test_accuracy': test_acc,
        'test_f1': test_f1,
        'test_sensitivity': test_sensitivity,
        'conf_matrix': conf_matrix,
        'history': history_list
    }

    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(resultados, f)

    print("Resultados guardados en", file_path)

# Ejecutar el entrenamiento con validación cruzada
cross_validate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_folds=5)

I have attempted several strategies to improve GPU utilization:

Increased Batch Size: I increased the batch size to 256, expecting that larger batches would utilize the GPU more effectively and reduce the training time per epoch.

Using tf.data.Dataset: I implemented the tf.data.Dataset API with prefetch to optimize data loading and processing, expecting this would help keep the GPU fed with data continuously during training.

Multiprocessing: I set use_multiprocessing=True and increased the number of workers to 8 during training to see if parallel data loading could alleviate the bottleneck. I expected that this would allow for more efficient use of the CPU, enabling faster data preparation.

Monitoring GPU Usage: I continuously monitored the GPU usage with nvidia-smi to ensure that memory was being allocated properly and to identify any patterns in utilization.


Despite these efforts, the GPU utilization remains low (0-5%) while the memory usage is close to 100%. I expected that by implementing these changes, the GPU would show higher utilization and consequently improve the training speed of my model.

What is your question?

How's the disk usage? Maybe your batch sizes are so large that the disk is actually the bottleneck.

@desertnaut my question is why is my GPU utilization only 0-5% during TensorFlow model training, even though the memory is fully used, and how can I improve GPU usage efficiency?

You're definitely not using the GPU; the code doesn't run automatically on the GPU. You need to specify which functions you want to run on the GPU by using the @jit decorator from the Numba library. With the GPU, the code you provided shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to execute (I'm exaggerating). You'll know you're using the GPU because the task manager will show 100% usage.

I thought I was using it because when I run the code, the memory usage increases from 0.6 GB to 3.7 GB out of 12, and the temperature rises from 38°C to 78°C. Additionally, in the task manager, the CUDA graph shows 91% usage.

An adequate answer would provide a code example using jit with the OP's code. NOTE that numba is NOT required for GPU use with tensorflow.
